# Runtime Dynamic Breakpoint Toggling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

During the execution of a C# program I'm debugging, I'd like Visual Studio to automatically toggle-on a set of breakpoints if a certain condition is met *while the program is executing*.

Is this possible?  Do I need a special edition, such as Enterprise edition?  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

### Breakpoint Actions

I notice that I can label Visual Studio breakpoints.  I also notice that breakpoints have an "action" I can set.  In Community edition, the only action I can take is to log to the output window.  It would be perfect if there was an action that allowed me to toggle-on all breakpoints that have the tag "foobar".

### Breakpoint Conditions

I'm also not seeing what I need with conditional breakpoints.  For example, I do not see a way to say "break here, only if a *different* breakpoint with the label `watch-out` has already been executed".  If this feature exists in the Enterprise edition, then perhaps that is my answer...time to upgrade!

### Summary

Is what I'm seeking possible in Visual Studio?  Or is there a VS extension or 3rd party tool that will give this ability?  I wonder if this is something already offered through intellitrace?

Comment: Can you clarify why [conditional breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#Anchor_8) won't work for you?

Comment: @BJMyers I added clarification. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - VS Enterprise Edition does not have breakpoint conditions that depend on other breakpoints.  The only options are conditional expressions (using in-scope variables), hit count, and filters for thread ID, machine name, etc.